# Cannot add Firebase to SwiftPackage; error inside the Firebase-Package

Tags: swift, firebase, dependencies, swift-package-manager

At the moment I try to create a Swift Package with the Firebase-Framework. I need FirebaseAuth, FirebaseFirestore, FirebaseFirestoreSwift and FirebaseStorage
My PackageManager:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v12), .iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk", from: "10.10.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseFirestore", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseFirestoreSwift", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseStorage", package: "firebase-ios-sdk")
            ],
        path: "Sources/MyPackage"
        )
    ]
)
```

When I start the app I get the error messages: `Module 'GTMSessionFetcherCore' not found`, `'FBLPromises.h' file not found` and `product 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift-Beta' required by package 'myPackage' target 'myPackage' not found in package 'firebase-ios-sdk'.`

What did I wrong? Someone has written, that `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` is called `FirebaseFirestoreSwift-Beta`, but then it doesn't work either... I don't know what to do! Thanks for any help!